# vnote to txt converter

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any software to convert vnote(vnt) to txt in linux?

I found [vnote2text](https://bitbucket.org/eug48/vnote2txt/downloads) for windows but none for linux

Comment: I have some vnote files that I'd like to open on linux, and this question is the top hit for "vnt linux vnote". It is 3 years later, another county, and admittedly the same os. Thus, I think closing this as 'too localized' was the wrong call. Please consider reopening it.

Answer (score 2):

Run it from the command line: `python vnote2txt.pyw`. It's just a script, not a complied executable or anything.

(It's just named as `*.pyw` to take advantage of some oddity on the Windows Python distribution).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Online solution, where you don't have to run anything from your computer.

The site is: https://sites.google.com/site/vnotetotextconverter/

You just copy your Vnote / vnt contents, paste it in the text box, click convert.
The results should appear in the second text box.